# Error when trying to access NASA HLS dataset requiring netrc authentication using R and gdalcubes

Tags: gdal, r, landsat, sentinel-2, stac

I am using gdalcubes to process Sentinel 2 data (https://github.com/appelmar/gdalcubes). The code I use works perfectly with S 2 data on AWS. But when trying to use the Harmonized Landsat-Sentinel product (https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/hlss30v002/), I fail. The product is secured using a netrc file which stores username and password. GDAL can directly access the files in Cloud OPtimized GeoTIFF (COG) format, which works using the r terra package after dapting some GDAL configurations (see here https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/608)
I tried `gdalcubes_set_gdal_config` to set these same options plus the nerc options I found here (terra works without these): https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html
For the rstac package, which is called previously to query the STAC catalog, options are passed through the post request, which works (see code example below).
Here is my reproducible example:

```r
library(rstac)
library(sf)
library(gdalcubes)
library(terra)
library(stars)

gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_HTTP_NETRC", "YES")
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_HTTP_NETRC_FILE", "/home/ubuntu/.netrc") #replace with your path
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL", "YES")
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEFILE", ".rcookies")
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEJAR", ".rcookies")
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN", "EMPTY_DIR")
gdalcubes_set_gdal_config("CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS", "TIF")

setGDALconfig(c("GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL=YES", 
                "GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEFILE=.rcookies",
                "GDAL_HTTP_COOKIEJAR=.rcookies", 
                "GDAL_DISABLE_READDIR_ON_OPEN=EMPTY_DIR",
                "CPL_VSIL_CURL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS=TIF"))


s = stac("https://cmr.earthdata.nasa.gov/stac/LPCLOUD")
bbox <- c(27.36, -5.153, 30.469, 2.112433)
start <- "2018-08-01T00:00:00Z")
end <- f"2018-08-31T00:00:00Z")
netrc <- "/home/ubuntu/.netrc"  #a sample - replace with your path
#test STAC
items <- s %>%
  stac_search(collections = "HLSS30",
              bbox = bbox,
              datetime = paste(start,end, sep = "/")) %>%
  post_request(config(netrc = TRUE, netrc_file = netrc), set_cookies("LC" = "cookies"))

assets <- c("B02", "B03", "B04")
col <- stac_image_collection(items$features, asset_names = assets, 
                             property_filter = function(x) {x[["eo:cloud_cover"]] < 30})

al <- assets_url(items, asset_names = assets)
#test terra
cog <- rast(paste0("/vsicurl/", al[1]))
mycrs <- crs(cog, describe=T)
epsg <- mycrs$code

ll <- st_sfc(st_point(sabb[1:2]), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(st_crs(cog))
ur <- st_sfc(st_point(sabb[3:4]), crs = 4326) %>% st_transform(st_crs(cog))

v = cube_view(srs = epsg,  extent = list(t0 = as.character(startDate), t1 = as.character(endDate),
                                         left = ll[[1]][1], right = ur[[1]][1],  top = ur[[1]][2], bottom = ll[[1]][2]),
              dx = 30, dy = 30, dt = "P5D", aggregation = "median", resampling = "bilinear")

gdalcubes_options(parallel = 4) 
bands <- c("B04","B03", "B02")
medianRGB <- function(col, v){
  raster_cube(col, v) %>%
    select_bands(bands) %>%
    reduce_time(c("median(B04)", "median(B03)", "median(B02)"))
}
#test gdalcubes
medianRGB(col, v) %>%
              st_as_stars() -> RGBout
write_stars(RGBout, "out.tif", type = "Int16")
```

The error occures at `st_as_stars() -> RGBout` when gdalcube tries to get the data.

```r
Error in gdalcubes:::gc_exec_worker(j$cube, j$worker_id, j$worker_count,  : 
  c++ exception (unknown reason)
Execution halted
Error in gdalcubes:::gc_exec_worker(j$cube, j$worker_id, j$worker_count,  : 
  c++ exception (unknown reason)
Execution halted
Error in gdalcubes:::gc_exec_worker(j$cube, j$worker_id, j$worker_count,  : 
  c++ exception (unknown reason)
Execution halted
Error in gdalcubes:::gc_exec_worker(j$cube, j$worker_id, j$worker_count,  : 
  c++ exception (unknown reason)
Execution halted
Error in gc_eval_cube(x, fname, .pkgenv$compression_level, with_VRT, .pkgenv$ncdf_write_bounds,  : 
  one or more worker processes failed to compute data cube chunks
```

When trying a second time, R hangs and the session needs to be aborted.
I am afraid this could be a bug in gdalcubes, so I filed one here (https://github.com/appelmar/gdalcubes/issues/85) and it has to do with how the netrc authentication is handle in gdalcubes. But maybe I got the GDAL configuration wrong, and someone has already worked around this error.